# "С прошлых, а то и (с) позапрошлых лет". Повторять ли предлог С?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Знакомые с прошлых, а то и позапрошлых лет.*

*Знакомые с прошлых, а то и **с** позапрошлых лет.*

Как правильно написать?

Comment: С позапрошлыми годами Вам  сначала надо серьёзно разобраться.

Comment: @shampar, Про позапрошлые годы я задал отдельный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437241/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Прочитал, но ничего не вычитал. Рассуждения есть, выводы не сделаны. Разобраться Galyna Savytska придётся самой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу корректности употребления прилагательных *прошлый* и *позапрошлый* во множественном числе я задал отдельный вопрос: ["Прошлые", "позапрошлые" — можно ли так говорить?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437241/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c).

По поводу повторения предлога после слов "а то и" я думаю, что оба варианта допустимы. Но на мой вкус, в Вашем предложении повторение предлога пойдет на пользу.

Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Предлог повторен**

Особенно злобствовали те, кто когда-то хорошо начинал, а потом в силу разных причин стал топтаться на месте и постепенно отходил **на второй, а то и на третий план**. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

Но тогда почему же в большинстве цивилизованных стран принято отдавать детей в школу **с шести, а то и с пяти лет**? [Анна Фенько. Невроз по поведению // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2002]

**Предлог не повторен**

Одни люди используют ложь во благо, другие **в плохих, а то и вообще опасных целях**. [коллективный. Форум: Рецензия на фильм «Поймай меня, если сможешь» (2006-2011)]

Например, в тех случаях, когда, согласно наблюдениям очевидцев, НЛО, движущиеся с очень высокими скоростями, не применяя никакого торможения, резко меняют направление своего движения **на 90, а то и все 180 градусов**. [В. Н. Комаров. Тайны пространства и времени (1995-2000)]