# "Прошлые", "позапрошлые" — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, множественное-число

[Словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9) говорит, что *прошлый* — это предшествующий настоящему, минувший; прежний.

Значит ли это, что прошлым можно назвать только **непосредственно** предшествующий настоящему? На первый взгляд, да. Прошлый год только один — 2017, прошлое столетие — 20-й век. Тогда что такое прошлые годы, прошлые столетия? ("Из-за свечи, из сумерек, не знаю, из какого времени, из каких столетий, **прошлых** или будущих, он взглянул на меня невероятно чистыми голубыми глазами." О. Берггольц. Дневные звезды.)

Еще непонятней с *позапрошлым*.

ПОЗАПРОШЛЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Разг. Непосредственно предшествующий прошлому, только что прошедшему. П-ая неделя. П-ая ночь. П. год. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9))

Тут явно указано: "**непосредственно** предшествующий **только что прошедшему**".
Казалось бы, всем должно быть ясно, что неграмотно говорить "позапрошлые годы". 
Однако в Нацкорпусе находим:

В этом месте и в прошлом году, и **позапрошлые годы** не хвалились хорошей погодой: до ильина дня стоит жар, в ильин день пройдет над горой сердитая гроза ― и потом дождик, который так и идет целые две недели; а ныне грозы не было, зато дождь начался с половины июля и, хотя он идет не постоянно, но все-таки идет, то через час, то через полчаса. [Ф. М. Решетников. Горнорабочие (1866)]

Несовременно? Устарело? Помогите разобраться.

P.S. Есть еще один случай, который, по-моему, нужно рассматривать отдельно. Когда мы имеем дело с понятием, выраженным множественным числом. Например "выходные", то есть конец недели. В этом случае употребление множественного числа выглядит естественным: *прошлые выходные, позапрошлые выходные*

Answer (score 1):

Примеры - из художественной речи. И это не случайно. В данном случае требование логической точности уступает место требованию точности образного смысла.  И в том и в другом случае на употребление прилагательных прошлый/позапрошлый влияет семантика субстантивированного существительного "прошлое", то есть мы имеем дело здесь с образными определениями - эпитетами (хотя и стертыми).

Answer (score 0):

Позапрошлые выходные... Здесь нет мн. числа (выходные — существительное), и только эта **пара дней** идёт строго за минувшей, прошлой парой.

Все остальные устойчивые (с определением *позапрошлый*) также не должны иметь мн. числа, т. к. их конкретика множественностью размывается и не может быть признана информативной. *Позапрошлые годы*, поэтому, есть выражение бессмысленное: числа таких годов не имеется, оно бесконечно.

«И в прошлом году, и позапрошлые годы» можно заменить одним словом *никогда*.

Comment: "Никогда раньше" и "позапрошлые годы" имеют разный смысл.

Comment: Цитируйте полностью: «И в прошлом году, и позапрошлые годы». Между тем — спасибо, убрал лишнее слово «раньше».

Comment: "В прошлом году ничего" в данном случае ничего не добавляет. Но "и в прошлом году, и позапрошлые годы" и "никогда" тоже имеют разные значения. Никогда это никогда. А "позапрошлые годы" относятся только к нескольким последним годам. Лет тридцать-пятьдесять назад уже не входят в "позапрошлые годы", но входят в "никогда",

Comment: Аргументируйте. Напишите свой ответ, так проще будет.

Comment: Что именно аргументировать?

Comment: Лет тридцать-пятьдесять назад уже не входят в "позапрошлые годы", но входят в "никогда", – Сибиряк

Comment: Что тут аргументировать? Русский язык?